# How to connect to a user's google account using JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Show user's Google Documents spreadsheets by logging into their google account using javascript. I have a login page for this. If login was succesful, user's spreadsheets should be seen. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Google API you need to create an App, register it and authenticate it from the user before you can access his/her data on Google servers. This might help you to get started :

- [http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts) : An Introduction to Authentication using OAuth Protocol
- http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/ : OAuth playground , where you can experiment with code to learn how to use OAuth
- You can register the domain URL of your application over here : https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use Loginza (http://loginza.ru) as ready-to-use solution.